# Put 4 divs (children) in the corners of the parent

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set the position of 4 `div`s in the corners of the parent div. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="resize">
    <div class="n w res"></div>
    <div class="n e res"></div>
    <div class="s e res"></div>
    <div class="s w res"></div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
```

I cannot understand why the `.res` divs are not positioned in the corners...

How can I fix this?

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/54kuF/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change position type of `.res` to `absolute` and insert `position:relative` in class `resize`
Absolute divs need to be included inside a div with position relative to work fine. 
try this:

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/54kuF/1/)

Comment: Correct. I was just writing an answer. Can you explain your code to the OP.

Comment: Thank you, all! Accepting this in few minutes!

Comment: Glad to help you @イオニカビザウ

Answer (score 1):

To get your aim, you must use `position:absolute;` for the `.res` divs.
The parent of an absolutely positioned `div` (in your example `.resize`) must be relatively positionned.

More info [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/54kuF/3/)**

CSS :

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:absolute;

}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for the small rectangles. This means relative to the original position.

To position them in the corners, relative to their parent, you must use

```css
.resize {
    position: relative;
}
.resize .res {
    position: absolute;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54kuF/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

html:

```
<div class="resize">
    <div class="n w res"></div>
    <div class="n e res"></div>
    <div class="s e res"></div>
    <div class="s w res"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54kuF/7/)

The property `position` creates a new [block formatting context](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/). And this context will be relative to the next ancestor with a `position` property defined.

Answer (score 1):

I would position the resize div `relative` and the contained four divs `absolute` (assuming that the four divs should be *inside* the resize div):

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

.resize .res.n { top: 0px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: 0px; }
.resize .res.w { left: 0px; }
.resize .res.e { right: 0px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give position relatve to resize div
and in inner div will be position absolute.

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add position: relative to .resize and position: absolute to .resize .res

http://jsfiddle.net/flocsy/54kuF/8/

```
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
}

.resize .res.n { top: -4px; }
.resize .res.s { bottom: -4px; }
.resize .res.w { left: -4px; }
.resize .res.e { right: -4px; }

.resize {
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `position`, you have to set `parent as relative` and `child as absolute`

**demo here**

You have not set `position` of parent, thats the fault :

```
.resize{
   position: relative; /*this was missing */
}
.resize .res {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute; /*this was updated*/
}
```